# Encountering errors running stats.pearsonr on two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to run stats.pearsonr on two columns (height and sprintspeed) in my dataframe. The problem is:

i.) If i run stats.pearsonr without removing the NaN values in my height column the result is (nan,1)

ii.) If i first remove the nan values in height then the error message is that these two columns have different shapes

```
 fifa_dataset['Height'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

iii.) If i drop na values for the entire dataframe I lose too much data (some players in my dataframe for example have NaN values for teams, value, transfer price etc).

```
fifa_dataset['Height'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

Prior to this I changed the values in the height column to strings:

```
fifa_dataset['Height']= fifa_dataset.Height.str.split("'").str.join('.').apply(lambda x: (float(x)*30.48)).dropna().astype(int)
```

This is the dataset I am interacting with
[Data](https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19/downloads/fifa19.zip/4)

I assume it may have something to do with the values in the height appearing to be floats (e.g 178.0) despite having converted the values to ints in my lambda function
Sample of height column:

```
0    173.0
1    188.0
2    179.0
3    195.0
4    155.0
Name: Height, dtype: float64
```

Sample of SprintSpeed column:

```
0    86.0
1    91.0
2    90.0
3    58.0
4    76.0
Name: SprintSpeed, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issues by using spearmanr to test correlation and adding nan_policy='omit' argument:

```
height_corr = stats.spearmanr(fifa_dataset['Height'], fifa_dataset['SprintSpeed'], nan_policy='omit')
```